# Seekbar not progressing inside Cursor Adaptor

Tags: android, android-seekbar

I have a seekbar in my cursor adaptor, code below, when I am playing a song I am supposed to increment it, I have a separate utility class, but the problem is the seekbar is not progressing at all, even if I hard code it, but the log cat is showing my calculations fine which I commented in my run handler.

When I am sliding the seekbar "onStartTrackingTouch" and "onStopTrackingTouch" is responding fine with proper integer value. Music is played via a service which is working fine too.

Where am I going wrong ?

```
package com.kavayah.spotifystreamer;

import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.media.Image;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

import com.kavayah.spotifystreamer.data.SpotifyContract;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Call;
import com.squareup.picasso.MemoryPolicy;
import com.squareup.picasso.NetworkPolicy;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class TrackPlayerAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

private final static String LOG_TAG = TrackPlayerAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

private static Context context;
private SpotifyMusicService mSpotifyMusicService;
private Intent playIntent;
private boolean iSMusicServiceBoundToActivity = false;
private static ServiceConnection spotifyMusicConnection;
private Handler mDurationHandler = new Handler();
private SeekBar mSpotifyMusicSeekBar;
private static int mDuration_ms;
private Utility utils;

//declare a interface which will communicate with the fragment
Callback callback;

public interface Callback {
    /**
     * DetailFragmentCallback for when an item has been selected.
     */
    public void playItemSelected();
    public void nextItemSelected(Uri trackUri);
}

/*
public TrackPlayerAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags){
    super(context, c, flags);
    trackPlayerActivityFragment = new TrackPlayerActivityFragment();
}
*/

public TrackPlayerAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags, Callback callback) {
    super(context, c, flags);
    this.context = context;
    this.callback = callback;

    utils = new Utility();

    //connect to the service
    spotifyMusicConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            SpotifyMusicService.SpotifyMusicBinder binder = (SpotifyMusicService.SpotifyMusicBinder) service;
            //get the service
            mSpotifyMusicService = binder.getService();
            iSMusicServiceBoundToActivity = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, ">>>>> Music service disconnected.");
            iSMusicServiceBoundToActivity = false;
        }
    };


}


@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (playIntent == null) {
        playIntent = new Intent(context, SpotifyMusicService.class);
        context.bindService(playIntent, spotifyMusicConnection, context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        context.startService(playIntent);
    }


    int viewType = getItemViewType(cursor.getPosition());
    int layoutId = -1;
    layoutId = R.layout.list_item_player;
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(layoutId, parent, false);
    TrackPlayerViewHolder trackPlayerViewHolder = new TrackPlayerViewHolder(view);
    view.setTag(trackPlayerViewHolder);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, final Context context, final Cursor cursor) {

    TrackPlayerViewHolder trackPlayerViewHolder = (TrackPlayerViewHolder) view.getTag();
    int viewType = getItemViewType(cursor.getPosition());

    String artistIcon = cursor.getString(TrackPlayerActivityFragment.COL_ALBUM_ICON2);
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, ">>>>> TrackPlayerActivityFragment.COL_ALBUM_ICON2 " + artistIcon);

    if (artistIcon != null && !artistIcon.equals("")) {
        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(artistIcon)
                .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE)
                .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)
                .tag(context)
                .into(trackPlayerViewHolder.iconView);
    } else {
        trackPlayerViewHolder.iconView.setImageResource(0);
    }

    String artistName = cursor.getString(TrackPlayerActivityFragment.COL_ARTIST_NAME);
    trackPlayerViewHolder.artistNameView.setText(artistName);

    String albumName = cursor.getString(TrackPlayerActivityFragment.COL_ALBUM_NAME);
    trackPlayerViewHolder.albumNameView.setText(albumName);

    String trackName = cursor.getString(TrackPlayerActivityFragment.COL_TRACK_NAME);
    trackPlayerViewHolder.trackNameView.setText(trackName);

    String duration = String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(TrackPlayerActivityFragment.COL_DURATION_MS));
    trackPlayerViewHolder.durationView.setText(duration);


    //implement the OnSeekBarChangeListener interface methods
    mSpotifyMusicSeekBar = (SeekBar) view.findViewById(R.id.musicSeekBar);
    mSpotifyMusicSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            if (fromUser) {
                Log.i("onProgressChanged", "" + progress);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i("onStartTrackingTouch",
                    "" + seekBar.getProgress());
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i("onStopTrackingTouch",
                    "" + seekBar.getProgress());
            mSpotifyMusicService.seek(seekBar.getProgress());

        }
    });


    final ToggleButton play_button = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.media_play);
    play_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (view != null) {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, ">>>>> play button click - " + cursor.getInt(TrackPlayerActivityFragment.COL_PRIMARY_TRACK_ID));
                //((Callback)trackPlayerActivityFragment).onItemSelected();
                callback.playItemSelected();

                mSpotifyMusicService.setSongURL(cursor.getString(TrackPlayerActivityFragment.COL_PREVIEW_URL));
                mSpotifyMusicService.playSong(cursor.getString(TrackPlayerActivityFragment.COL_TRACK_NAME));
                mDuration_ms = cursor.getInt(TrackPlayerActivityFragment.COL_DURATION_MS);
                mSpotifyMusicSeekBar.setProgress(0);
                mSpotifyMusicSeekBar.setMax(100);
                updateSeekbarProgress();
            }
        }

    });

    final ImageButton next_button = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.media_next);
    next_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (view != null) {
                Integer nextSongId = cursor.getInt(TrackPlayerActivityFragment.COL_PRIMARY_TRACK_ID);
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, ">>>>> next button click - " + ++nextSongId);
                //check to see if query return null, means it has reached the end of the
                // tracks list, stay of the last song even if the user presses next key
                Uri nextTrackUri = SpotifyContract.TrackEntry.buildTrackUri(nextSongId);
                Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(nextTrackUri, null, null, null, null);
                if (cur.getCount() < 1) {
                    //--nextSongId;
                    //nextTrackUri = SpotifyContract.TrackEntry.buildTrackUri(nextSongId);
                } else {
                    callback.nextItemSelected(nextTrackUri);
                }
                if(cur.getCount() > 0){
                    cur.moveToFirst();
                    mSpotifyMusicService.setSongURL(cur.getString(TrackPlayerActivityFragment.COL_PREVIEW_URL));
                    mSpotifyMusicService.playSong(cur.getString(TrackPlayerActivityFragment.COL_TRACK_NAME));

                }
                //Intent intent = new Intent(context, TrackPlayerActivity.class);
                //intent.setData(SpotifyContract.TrackEntry.buildTrackUri(nextSongId));
                //context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });

    final ImageButton prev_button = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.media_prev);
    prev_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (view != null) {
                Integer prevSongId = cursor.getInt(TrackPlayerActivityFragment.COL_PRIMARY_TRACK_ID);
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, ">>>>> prev button click - " + --prevSongId);
                //check if the query returns null, means it has reached the beginning
                //increment the track id, else it will show null.
                Uri prevTrackUri = SpotifyContract.TrackEntry.buildTrackUri(prevSongId);
                Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(prevTrackUri, null, null, null, null);
                if (cur.getCount() < 1) {
                    //++prevSongId;
                    //prevTrackUri = SpotifyContract.TrackEntry.buildTrackUri(prevSongId);
                } else {
                    callback.nextItemSelected(prevTrackUri);
                }
                if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
                    cur.moveToFirst();
                    mSpotifyMusicService.setSongURL(cur.getString(TrackPlayerActivityFragment.COL_PREVIEW_URL));
                    mSpotifyMusicService.playSong(cur.getString(TrackPlayerActivityFragment.COL_TRACK_NAME));

                }

            }
        }
    });



}
public void updateSeekbarProgress(){
    mDurationHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateSeekbarTime, 100);
}

private Runnable mUpdateSeekbarTime = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //long totalDuration = mSpotifyMusicService.getDur();
        long currentDuration = mSpotifyMusicService.getPosn();
        // Updating progress bar
        int progress = (int)(utils.getProgressPercentage(currentDuration, mDuration_ms));
        //Log.i(LOG_TAG, " Seekbar position : " + progress);

        mSpotifyMusicSeekBar.setProgress(progress);
        mDurationHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
    }

};

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have only one `Adapter Object` and only one `mSpotifyMusicSeekBar` variable and `bind()` is called multiple times, each time for every visible list item.

By the time the Handler is called, the `seekBar` reference is changed so you never see the progress because some other `seekbar` is getting updated.

I tried a sample of your code. And here it is - and - seek bar is getting updated as expected:

```
public class TrackPlayerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TrackPlayerAdapter.MyHolder>
{
    private final static String TAG = TrackPlayerAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    private Context context;

    public TrackPlayerAdapter(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i)
    {
        LinearLayout container = new LinearLayout(context);
        container.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        container.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams
                .MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        SeekBar seekbar = new SeekBar(context);
        seekbar.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams
                .MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        Button button = new Button(viewGroup.getContext());
        button.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams
                .WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        button.setText("play");

        seekbar.setTag("SEEKBAR");
        button.setTag("BUTTON");
        container.addView(seekbar);
        container.addView(button);
        return new MyHolder(container);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyHolder myHolder, int i)
    {
        myHolder.bind();
    }

    /**
     * Get the row id associated with the specified position in the list.
     *
     * @param position The position of the item within the adapter's data set whose row id we want.
     * @return The id of the item at the specified position.
     */
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        return 3;
    }

    public static class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        private Handler mDurationHandler = new Handler();
        private SeekBar mSpotifyMusicSeekBar;
        private Button mToggleButton;
        int totalProgress = 0;

        public void updateSeekbarProgress()
        {
            mDurationHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateSeekbarTime, 100);
        }

        private Runnable mUpdateSeekbarTime = new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                if(totalProgress <= 10000)
                {
                    totalProgress += 100;
                    int progress = (int) ((float) totalProgress / 100);
                    mSpotifyMusicSeekBar.setProgress(progress);
                    mDurationHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                }
            }

        };

        public MyHolder(View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);
            mSpotifyMusicSeekBar = (SeekBar)itemView.findViewWithTag("SEEKBAR");
            mToggleButton = (Button) itemView.findViewWithTag("BUTTON");
        }

        public void bind()
        {
            mSpotifyMusicSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)
                {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onProgressChanged::" + progress);
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.i(TAG, "onStartTrackingTouch::" + seekBar.getProgress());
                }

                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.i(TAG, "onStopTrackingTouch" + seekBar.getProgress());

                }
            });


            mToggleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    mSpotifyMusicSeekBar.setProgress(0);
                    mSpotifyMusicSeekBar.setMax(100);
                    updateSeekbarProgress();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```